# Как вернуть список с помощью функции в Haskell

Tags: haskell

Нужно вернуть списком или еще каким-нибудь образом вывести в консоль результат подсчета 2 уравнений.К примеру,нужно вывести результат от x+y и x*y,отдавая хаскелю только команду, наподобие:

```
prelude->reshu 2 3
5 6
```

или `[5,6]`
или еще каким-нибудь образом, пока накидал так

```
reshu :: Float -> Float -> [Float,Float]
reshu [x y] = [side,corner]
 where side  = sqrt ((y/2)^2+x^2)
       corner = atan(2*x/y)
```

Но тут не рабочий вариант, я игрался с типами аргументов и выводом, а также со строкой

```
 reshu [x y] = [side,corner]
```

Пробовал еще сделать такое

```
side  = sqrt ((y/2)^2+x^2) : []
```

И потом в вызываемой функции так

```
reshu x y = side ++ corner
```

Как грамотно сделать вывод двух значений без написания 2 функций и отдельного обращения к ним? Желательно не сильно сложно, только первое занятие как начали изучать ФП.

UPD.

Все, разобрался, вот рабочий код

```
reshu :: Float -> Float -> [Float]
reshu x y = [side,corner]
 where side  = sqrt ((y/2)^2+x^2)
       corner = atan(2*x/y)
```

Comment: Что именно не работает?

Comment: Подучите язык, хотя бы самый базовый синтаксис и типы, пока вы просто вбиваете код наугад. `reshu x y = [side, corner] where ...` `reshu :: Float -> Float -> [Float]`

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий код:

```hs
reshu :: Float -> Float -> [Float]
reshu x y = [side,corner]
 where side  = sqrt ((y/2)^2+x^2)
       corner = atan(2*x/y)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]